# How does the Recycle Bin in Windows work?

Tags: windows, recycle-bin

What does the Recycle Bin in Windows actually do? Is it just a glorified folder and a holding place for soon to be deleted files, or does it do something specific?

Specifically, are files that are "moved" to the Recycle Bin actually moved on the hard disc, or are just the pointers to the files moved? I am a fairly experienced user, I just wanted a more depth explanation of the Recycle Bin.

Comment: This is actually an interesting question. If the recycle bin were simple, it wouldn't take forever to add a folder with a few thousand files to it.

Comment: Start with [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trash_(computing)#Microsoft_Windows).

Comment: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/95622-45-recycle-work

Comment: The best info is always from the folks who actually write recovery software: http://www.pandorarecovery.com/knowledge_base/general/recycler.php . And also see http://dereknewton.com/2010/06/recycle-bin-forensics-in-windows-7-and-vista/ and http://linuxsleuthing.blogspot.sg/2009/10/processing-vista-recyclebin.html and http://www.cybersecurityinstitute.biz/INFO2.htm

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The reference is removed, a metadata file is kept in the Recycle Bin to know the original location.

In the early days, on Windows 95 and 98 this was located in `\RECYCLED`. On Windows 2000 and later it was renamed to `\RECYCLER`. Since Windows Vista it is now a special folder called  `\$Recycle.Bin`.

Use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see the I/O under the hood, put a filter on `Recycle.Bin` and visit it. :)

For example, when I do this:

```
notepad \$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-21-0192837465-987654321-0123456789-1000\$EXAMPL5
```

**Note:** The long folder name is a [User SID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier). The last folder name is a hash based on the metadata.

I get a file that contains metadata information like this:

```
                Ö¸ÌC : \ P a t h \ T o \ S o m e \ E x a m p l e . t x t
```

The reason that the file path has spaces in between is because it is stored in wide byte chars, to support special characters for certain languages as well as unicode and what else. The earlier symbols are binary and contain information like the file size and permissions, as well as a pointer to the file data. In essence, it contains enough information to reconstruct the original reference...

It's sad that the Windows Internals book doesn't cover this, or else I would've had more reference. I haven't found any articles that go into detail on this, neither by Microsoft or by third party people. They probably do exist but I found it easier to go and reverse engineer the main concept...

Comment: Nice, I just find out the hard way exactly what you've posted. Do you have any idea how to find your `Example.txt` from the command prompt? My use case is to search the entire drive for a misplaced file using `dir c:\*.doc* /a/s` but it doesn't find any docs in the recycle bin because of the renaming and the real name being kept in this metadata file.

Comment: That will probably involve findstr to grep the   recycle bin contents. Dunno how though.

Comment: Probably easier to update my expectations of `dir /a/s` :). tx Tom.

Comment: @TomWijsman, Weird, I can actually rename `C:\$Recycle.Bin` (tried on win8)! Is it safe to do so?

Answer (score 1):

I've done some extensive research on this, as it seems, surprisingly, there is very few info available online on how Recycle Bin actually implemented.

Everything is not that hard to grasp. When you delete file in the Bin, it is not actually moved to it.

First, lets take a look at the subfolders of `$Recycle.Bin`:

- `C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-18` is folder for built-in SYSTEM account
- `C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-1XXX\`, starting from 1000 are non-built in user folders. You should first check which one of them is the one you need by typing `whoami /all` in command prompt to get your SID, or `wmic useraccount get name,sid` to get all local accounts SIDs, then choose the folder matching with SID.

If you give security rights to your account to all this folders, Explorer might show your deleted files in every folder, however its just Explorer bug. If you navigate to, say, `C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-18` folder and type `dir /a`, you will see that its actually empty, and only folder that match with your SID contains your deleted files.

Note that even if you are the only user on the PC, you might still have folder `C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-1000\` that most likely will be empty. Then your actual folder will be `...-1001\`. User "1000" seems to be dangling folder for user that was created automatically by Windows on installation or some updates, then deleted. But `Recycle.Bin` folder wasn't destroyed and just stayed there. I assume that its safe to delete this dangling folder. I'm not so sure about `C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-18`, but I'm fairly sure its safe too, as there is no need for OS SYSTEM account to use the Bin, anyway.

So, here is deletion algorithm:

1. System creates [hardlink](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/hard-links-and-junctions) of the deleted file in `C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-1XXX\` folder with the name `$RXXXXXX.<file_ext>`, where `XXXXXX` is 6 symbols HASH calculated based on the file contents, as I assume.
2. Metadata file is created in the same folder with the name `$IXXXXXX.<file_ext>`. I will show you the content of this file later.
3. Original file is deleted, but because of extra hardlink in `$Recycle.Bin`, actual file's data stays in the same location on the drive as if file where never touched. It is not moved anywhere. This is why each logical volume must have it's own `$Recycle.Bin` folder, as hardlinks only work within the same volume.

That's about it. Restoration algorithm:

1. Metadata file is read and hardlink of `$RXXXXXX.<file_ext>` is created based on `$IXXXXXX.<file_ext>`'s info in original file location, with original file name.
2. Both metadata and backup file are deleted from `$Recycle.Bin`

Pretty simple, ain't it?

Now, the most interesting part is that metadata file:

```
0000  02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  <-- File header (QW)
0008  00 7C 0A 00 00 00 00 00  <-- File size (QW)
0010  90 83 72 44 28 9C D8 01  <-- File deletion date (QW)
0018  18 00 00 00|43 00 3A 00  <-- File path string length (DW)
0020  5C 00 24 00 52 00 65 00  
0028  63 00 79 00 63 00 6C 00
0030  65 00 2E 00 42 00 69 00
0038  6E 00 5C 00 66 00 73 00
0040  73 00 2E 00 65 00 78 00
0048  65 00 00 00|             <-- |Null-terminated path string| (wchar_t)
```

All values are in [Little Endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) format.

Header is fixed and its identical for all the files. Be warned that some `$I` files might have some junk bytes `FF FE` appear before the Header. I have no idea what are this for, so you should check for full header before reading further.

Deletion date is in [FILETIME](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-filetime) format and can be converted to usual [SYSTEMTIME](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-systemtime) via [FileTimeToSystemTime](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/nf-timezoneapi-filetimetosystemtime). It represents 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC).

So it's not super complicated file format, but quite interesting design.

I'm planing to use this info myself by creating custom "garbage collector" for Windows, that I will add to task scheduler to launch periodically and scan\delete files that where deleted more than 24 hours ago, etc. I know that Windows 10 has built-in option for this, but it's not flexible and not reliable (it sometimes leaves metadata files, while only deleteing `$R` files). Also, I think, previous Windows versions doesn't have this feature at all.

I encourage you to experiment with this too! For example, your program might save metadata info of all files it removes into some database, so you would have full history of all files you ever deleted!

Comment: [Sample output](https://i.imgur.com/ZUPEFBb.png) from my program. Garbage collection seems to also work as expected.

Comment: You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/ScienceDiscoverer/windows_tools).