# How does the Recyle bin work?

Tags: windows, recycle-bin

I have been thinking about this lately and I was just wondering "how does the recycle bin work?"

I mean, when I delete something, does the computer fully compress it and then store the file somewhere?

I'm slightly confused with the concept. I have looked at the similar [post](https://superuser.com/questions/368890/what-does-the-recycle-bin-do) but I am asking more specifically.

Comment: @downvoters, please indicate why you have decided to downvote the question. I would like to know how I can improve the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trash_%28computing%29)

In computing, the trash (also known as the recycle bin and by other names) is temporary storage for files that have been deleted in a file manager by the user, but not yet permanently erased from the file system. Typically, a recycle bin is presented as a special file directory to the user (whether or not it is actually a single directory depends on the implementation), allowing the user to browse deleted files, undelete those that were deleted by mistake, or delete them permanently (either one by one, or by the "Empty Trash" function).

Within a trash folder, a record is kept of each file and/or directory's original location. On certain operating systems, files must be moved out of the trash before they can be accessed again.

Whether or not files deleted by a program go to the recycle bin depends on its level of integration with a particular desktop environment and its function. Low-level utilities usually bypass this layer entirely and delete files immediately. A program that includes file manager functionality may or may not send files to the recycle bin, or it may allow the user to choose between these options.