# Recycle Bin storage location

Tags: windows, data-recovery, file-format, recycle-bin

I am interested to know, in which location and format are files stored when we put them in Recycle Bin? And when we delete them, where they go?

Comment: @DavidPostill I think you might be right based on the OPs comments to the current answer here. Unfortunately I can't change my dupe flag destination.

Comment: @Burgi No worries, hopefully any new voters will choose the right dupe ;)

Answer (score 0):

Open Windows Explorer and enter:

```
C:\$Recycle.Bin
```

You'll see hidden directories named `\$Recycle.Bin\%SID%`, where `%SID%` is the SID of the user that performed the deletion.

If you delete the file from Recycle Bin, his handle will be deleted from the File Allocation Table / Master File Table (the file itself will NOT be deleted!).

If you defrag your hard disk, the file will be deleted finally :)

[EDITED]

About a format of the files in the Bin [please take a look](https://superuser.com/questions/368890/how-does-the-recycle-bin-work/368893#368893):

> The reference is removed, a metadata file is kept in the Recycle Bin
>   to know the original location.

Comment: And whats the format of deleted files in that $Resycle.Bin directory? Does it also uses our HDD space even if it is deleted?

Comment: @duDE That comment (and parts of your answer) are not correct. See this answer [How does the Recycle Bin work?](http://superuser.com/a/368893). "a metadata file is kept in the Recycle Bin to know the original location"

Comment: Oh, have not knew this, sry, I have edited my answer ...